# Retrieve Second to Last Word in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, database, string, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.1

I have an address field where I am trying to extract the street type (`AVE`, `RD`, `ST`, etc). Some of them are formatted like this: `5th AVE N` or `PEE DEE RD N`

I have seen a few methods in PostgreSQL to count segments from the left based on spaces i.e. `split_part(name, ' ', 3)`, but I can't seem to find any built-in functions or regular expression examples where I can count the characters from the right.

My idea for moving forward is something along these lines:

```
select case when regexp_replace(name, '^.* ', '') = 'N'
            then *grab the second to last group of string values*
       end as type;
```

Comment: This is guaranteed to fail anywhere outside of a classroom.  Postal addresses are less uniform than women's dress sizes.  You should use an address verification service that returns the address in the components you're interested in separating out rather than trying to make the database do it on it's own.

Comment: Consider some of your clients could live in other countries, too.

Comment: There are only about 26k records in this data set so I'm pretty confident if I can accomplish this bit, then it will solve the problem.

Comment: This is only one county in one country.

Comment: @BaconBits what address verification service would you suggest?

Comment: If you're just in the US and you can meet the usage requirements (i.e., you send mail through the post office), then I would go with the [USPS API](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm) because it's free and fairly authoritative. If you need more than that, then there's lots of options. We have used SmartyStreets in the past, but that was many years ago and they have a much different licensing model now. Now we use ArcGIS under state contract because we mostly validate annually in batches. You will want to research and evaluate potential services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside the issue of robustness of this approach when applied to address data, you can extract the penultimate space-delimited substring in a string like this:

```
with a as (
    select string_to_array('5th AVE N', ' ') as addr
    )
select
    addr[array_length(addr, 1)-1] as street
from
    a;
```